# Comparing the value of a variable on json in C# to a string

Tags: c#, json, compare, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using a google API to get distance between two places and to check if I got distance information there's a status field on the json response for the API that can read "OK" or "NOT_AVAILABLE" or something along those lines. I want to check if the status is OK so I can use the distance info so I do it like this

```
if (disJSON["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["status"] == "OK")
```

The thing is that it returns false everytime even if the status is OK

I looked into the debugger to check the value and the value the debugger shows for the above element of the json is "\"OK\"". Which is weird. So I used that as the comparison string on the if statement like this

```
if (disJSON["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["status"] == "\"OK\"")
```

But it also returns false all the time. Any ideas how to compare this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the compile-time type of `disJSON["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["status"]` is `JToken` or something like that. If you cast to string, then a) you'll be comparing a string with a string; b) the compiler will use the `bool ==(string, string)` overload instead of comparing for reference identity:

```
string status = (string) disJSON["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["status"];
if (status == "OK")
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!